# jquery trigger h5Validate to display a error messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, eventtrigger

How can I trigger h5Validate and display the ("#error-email") when the class"ui-state-error"

I need to display the errors when the the h5Validate adds the class.

my eg: http://jsfiddle.net/hsSru/30/

thanks

Comment: This duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636608/jquery-html5-validation-with-error-messages

See my answer there.

Comment: Looks like you asked the same question twice, just one hour between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can override addClass to trigger an event :

```
(function(){
    // Your base, I'm in it!
    var originalAddClassMethod = jQuery.fn.addClass;

    jQuery.fn.addClass = function(){
        // Execute the original method.
        var result = originalAddClassMethod.apply( this, arguments );

        this.trigger('classChanged');

        // return the original result
        return result;
    }
})();
```

And then you can do your stuff :

```
$("#error-email").bind('classChanged', data, function(){
    if(this.hasClass("ui-state-error")){
        //do your stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: thansk pal, could you put it into a fiddle plz?